# How to make JavaFX editable comboBox opened?

Tags: combobox, javafx-2

How to open ComboBox automatically?

I have an editable ComboBox. I want it to be opened automatically, without forcing a user to click on it. 
How can it be done?
I've tried to make something like this:

```
testButton.fireEvent(new Event(ComboBox.ON_SHOWN));
```

But it does not work as I need: in the output I can see messages which signals that ON_SHOWN event was fired, but graphically my comboBox is still closed. Also, i've tried

```
testButton.fireEvent(new Event(ComboBox.ON_SHOWING));
```

but this shows no reaction at all. As well as

```
testButton.fireEvent(new Event(ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWING));
```

and

```
testButton.fireEvent(new Event(ComboBoxBase.ON_SHOWN));
```

PS: saying opened comboBox I mean something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Button btn = new Button("Show combobox");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        comboBox.show();
    }
});
```